# How to print set list to new lines in text file python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, file-handling

Basically I want to make a program where it reads a text file, does something with the info, and then outputs the different info into a file.

**For example;**
input.txt contains different lines with text

*Then I use this to convert to list:*

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
```

*Then outputting the list into a text file not like ['string', 'string'] but on new lines.*

Any help with this???

Comment: What have you tried? This sounds like a homework assignment.

Comment: What have I tried? What do you mean?

Comment: what have you done to try solving the problem yourself? @DMMOfficial

Comment: I have searched up online and stack, but I'm just getting started with coding tbh so yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat input.txt
 HELLO
 WORLD
```

In python you can use '\n' to append a new line to content.

```
   with open("input.txt") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        content = [x.strip() for x in content]
        content = '\n'.join(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the file and modifying the content in the list. The list can be written back to a text file with new line for each item in the list as given below:

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in my_list:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string  like this:

```
elements_on_new_line = '\n'.join(my_list)
```

And then you write on the file the variabile 'elements_on_new_line'

Doing this

```
with open('my file.txt', 'w') as my_file:
    my_file.write(elements_on_new_line)
```